# When to update persistence layer after the in-memory changes?

Tags: architecture, persistence, layer

I think the easiest way to make the question is with an example.

Let's say we have two classes "Log" and "Entry". "Log" has an Method "AddEntry(Entry entry)". 
On the UI the user types in the new entry and after a click on the button "Add Entry" =) the new entry wil be added to Log.
Now that just happens in the memory. How do I pass that change to the persistence layer? Does that happens in real time? Or do I make the change in-memory and then some module synchronizes them? 
I think I am missing a connecting point.

Comment: When you talk about persistence layer, are you talking about a custom layer which map and update change to your back end Or you are using any frameworks such as  Entity framework or similar ORM tools

Comment: @Nair Maybe I will use EF at some point. But for now it should be a custom layer.

Comment: In that case, it is EF responsibility to compare the changes and push respective changes to back-end when you instruct. For now, as and when you have some changes and ready to save, it is your responsibility ( responsibility of your data access wrapper) to capture and propagate using some stored procedure or DML statements

Comment: So I would implement someting that knows about the object-instance and when (not how) to insert it into the Data-Layer?